# Does "who does what" work in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

I am interested in knowing whether one can say "who does what" in the following context:

> All estimation methods are not yet on hand in standard software. For an overview of who does what, see (place reference here).

**edit according to andrewdotnich's comment**

The reference is the chapter of a book that describes a list of software that are able to deal with one or more of the estimation methods.

Comment: Is your reference to a list of software providers that support estimation methodologies? If so, saying that directly would be clearer.

If that's not what you meant, I'm not sure what your sentence means. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* say that, but it may not be clear (as per my comment to your question).

How about something like this?

> Software that supports all standard estimation methods is not currently available; for an overview of products that provide *partial* support, see [ref].

Comment: although saying "who *supports* what" might work just as well :)

Answer (score 2):

- your sentence is understandable (we understand that the reference will answer questions of actor and task)
- the wording of 'who does what' is not formal, it sounds very colloquial.
- by that, the sentence is 'grammatical' in an informal context.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I wanted to know whether or not "who deos what" sounds colloquial. Thx.